# C++ Selection Sort not sorting

Tags: c++, sorting

I copied a selection sort function straight from the book to apply to an array, but it is not properly sorting. Using cout to print elements 0, 10, and 19 give the original integers.

```
int main()
{

    int startScan, minIndex, minValue;
    int exchanges = 0;
    int selTestArray[20] = {84, 74, 65, 26, 37, 91, 94, 44, 52, 50, 50, 47, 34, 61, 70, 12, 59, 94, 61, 32};
    int size = 20;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++);
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = selTestArray[startScan];
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if (selTestArray[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = selTestArray[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        selTestArray[minIndex] = selTestArray[startScan];
        selTestArray[startScan] = minValue;
        exchanges++;
    }

    cout << exchanges << endl;
    cout << selTestArray[0] << endl;
    cout << selTestArray[10] << endl;
    cout << selTestArray[19] << endl;

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Sort is not sorting. How much arrays would the sort sort if the sort would sort arrays?

Comment: @Slava If you decide to post an aswer, post it as answer rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

on your first `for` loop you have a semicolon at the end:

```
for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++); 
//                                                ------^
```

you have an empty loop and a block of code that executed once.